# How to verify radio button is selected or not by default when it's not working with "isiselected()" method

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to verify if a radio button is selected or not by default?

The Xpath doesn't contain any attributes except the class and `ng-if` attribute (Angular web-app). I have tried using the `.isselected()` method, but it's not working in that way.

**HTML element for reference:**

`<div class="spriteImage12 radioButtonChecked ng-scope" data-ng-if="replaceDeactivateIouOfferListFlag"  style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;"></div>`

Comment: Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts –

Comment: Can you tell , what error you are getting when you are using isSelected method of selenium inbuilt library ?

Comment: I am getting below error.Due to this error i have changed my xpath in a different way and increased some wait. But still getting the same error:
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 128 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

Comment: Please update the Question with your code attempts and the relevant `HTML DOM`. Thanks

Comment: Please find my code below: boolean ReplaceFromSameIOU_selected=false;
   ReplaceFromSameIOU_selected=WebObjects_RL2.RelaceFromSameIOU_RadioBtn(driver).isSelected();
   if(ReplaceFromSameIOU_selected==true){
    System.out.println("Replace offering from same IOU has been selected as default seletion");
   }
   else{
    System.out.println("not selected");
   }

Comment: HTML DOM:
<div class="spriteImage12 radioButtonChecked ng-scope" data-ng-if="replaceDeactivateIouOfferListFlag" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;"></div>